# Creating sum within groups on multiple variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a table in Microsoft SQL Server with municipality IDs, company IDs and number of employees and I want to get the sum of employees per municipality and also the sum of employees per company Id and per municipality. So the table currently looks like this

```
| Municipality | Company Type ID | Number of Employees | Total employees in same municipality | Total Employees in same economic sector and same Municipality |
|--------------|-----------------|---------------------|--------------------------------------|---------------------------------------------------------------|
| 03212        | 10332           | 0                   |                                      |                                                               |
| 03212        | 10332           | 12                  |                                      |                                                               |
| 03212        | 10332           | 2                   |                                      |                                                               |
| 03212        | 10332           | 3                   |                                      |                                                               |
| 03212        | 10333           | 4                   |                                      |                                                               |
| 03212        | 10333           | 1                   |                                      |                                                               |
| 03133        | 10554           | 4                   |                                      |                                                               |
| 03133        | 10554           | 55                  |                                      |                                                               |
| 03133        | 10554           | 4                   |                                      |                                                               |
```

But I want to achieve something like this

```
| Municipality | Company Type ID | Number of Employees | Total employees in same municipality | Total Employees in same company ID and same Municipality |
|--------------|-----------------|---------------------|--------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------|
| 03212        | 10332           | 0                   | 22                                   | 17                                                       |
| 03212        | 10332           | 12                  | 22                                   | 17                                                       |
| 03212        | 10332           | 2                   | 22                                   | 17                                                       |
| 03212        | 10332           | 3                   | 22                                   | 17                                                       |
| 03212        | 10333           | 4                   | 22                                   | 5                                                        |
| 03212        | 10333           | 1                   | 22                                   | 5                                                        |
| 03133        | 10554           | 4                   | 63                                   | 59                                                       |
| 03133        | 10554           | 55                  | 63                                   | 59                                                       |
| 03133        | 10555           | 4                   | 63                                   | 4                                                        |
```

I have tried using the `SUM OVER PARTITION` but that only allows me to do it for one variable. How can I create the sum and insert it into the table over multiple variables

Comment: What db are u using?

Comment: @Aswin Microsoft SQL server

Comment: i hope you're sitting down but you can actually create another column that has a *different* over partition in sql server

Comment: `SUM([Number of Employees]) OVER (PARTITION BY Municipality, [Company Type ID])`  will work . [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Iu8D-hho)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sum(no of employees) over (partition by company type, Municipality) as 'Total Employees by Municipality
```

Something like that. It's just another column like you did previously .

I'm on mobile so formatting isn't correct .